# Unable to run python package (viztracer) from terminal

Tags: python, terminal, pip, pycharm, call-graph

I installed **code2flow** through pip install. But I'm unable to run my python script on viztracer in the terminal.

```
pip3 install viztracer 
viztracer mypythonfile.py
```

I'm using PyCharm's internal Terminal.

Getting the below error:

```
viztracer : The term 'viztracer' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

[image]

Can anyone help on this?

**mypythonfile.py**

```
import flask
from flask import request
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/binary_search", methods=["POST"])
def binary_search():


my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
target = request.form.get("target")
print("target: {}".format(target))
target = int(target)
first = 0
last = len(my_list) - 1
found = False

while first <= last and not found:
    midpoint = (first + last) // 2
    if my_list[midpoint] == target:
        found = True
    else:
        if target < my_list[midpoint]:
            last = midpoint - 1
        else:
            first = midpoint + 1

return flask.jsonify(found)

if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=2000, debug=False)
```

EDIT: Corrected the question.

Comment: From the message you have shown, it is clear that this is being hosted in `powershell.exe`, not `cmd.exe`. You should therefore use the host pertinent to your question tag, or change that tag from [[tag:cmd]] to [[tag:powershell]]. You should also consider whether you should be using the tag [[tag:terminal]]. If this is being run in the Windows Terminal, application, (`wt.exe`), please make that clear. Also, as the message is clearly a response from `mypythonfile.py`, it may be prudent to submit the content of that file too.

Comment: Replacing the [[tag:cmd]] with [[tag:pycharm]] has not made your question clearer. We need specifcs about your environment, so as well as making changes to your body text, you should use appropriate tags. Which terminal do you think you are you using? because I'm certain it is PowerShell. Also where is the content of your .py file? and how is everything configured, on your PC? We need to be able to reproduce your issue in order to fully understand it well enough to answer. Please try harder to help us to assist you.

Comment: You posted the lines `pip3 install code2flow
code2flow mypythonfile.py`. This is not how you run `viztracer` though at all. See [here](https://pypi.org/project/viztracer/0.1.1/)

Comment: Corrected the question. Please check if you can help on the question now.

Comment: @FlyingTeller I checked the page that you gave and tried the command  "python -m viztracer". result.json was generated. But I'm unable to view the result json using the command "python -m vizviewer .\result.json". Getting the error  "No module named vizviewer". Tried to pip install vizviewer. But its not working.

Comment: have you tried using an html file as output? Does `C:\users\hreka\appdata\roaming\python37\Scripts` exist and contain `vizviewer`?

Comment: @FlyingTeller Yes, the Scripts folder contains vizviewer. But how to generate output as html? When I ran the viztracer, the output was this - 

Total Entries: 776525                                                           
Use the following command to open the report:
vizviewer D:\Git\Pricing_New\DSR_Macd_Ill_Gvpn\result.json

And when I ran the given command, I got the 'No module named vizviewer error'.

Comment: Does running `C:\users\hreka\appdata\roaming\python37\Scripts\vizviewer D:\Git\Pricing_New\DSR_Macd_Ill_Gvpn\result.json` work?

Comment: @FlyingTeller Its working now! Got the chart in browser. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Great, the underlying issue is then only that that directory should have been part of PATH already. then you can run `vizviewer` directly without the absolute path to it. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory `C:\users\hreka\appdata\roaming\python37\Scripts` is probably not part of your `PATH` environment variable. You need to add it:

1. Run `rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables`
2. Select `PATH` and hit the `Edit` button
3. In the new window, select `new`, paste `C:\users\hreka\appdata\roaming\python37\Scripts` and then select `Ok`
4. Restart your system